# Mac terminal doesn't pass keys like C-/ to emacs

Tags: macos, terminal, emacs

I'm running emacs inside Mac OS Terminal.  Some key combinations are not working for emacs.
I tried the M-x describle-key (C-h k) in emacs to see what emacs is receiving when I press some key, it seems I can't get anything for the following:
C-, C-. C-/ C-; C-' C-1 C-2 ... C-0
Is there any configuration I should look at and tweak to make these key work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of those is expressible in a terminal program; you'll need a GUI (Aqua or X11) version of Emacs to use them.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.  Key sequences and term setting are always mystery to me, are there any good article to read about this?  I've been googling for awhile...  But most of the time, I'm running into lengthy terminal emulator spec.

Comment: Terminal emulators are limited to sending character sequences instead of events; since the `Ctrl` key is defined to remap the 0x40-0x5f/0x60-0x7f range to 0x00-0x1f, characters outside that range aren't guaranteed to do anything when `Ctrl` is applied to them.  There are some de-facto standards, mostly lifted from the behavior of the old Dec VTx00 series terminals (for example, `Ctrl`+`Space` sends 0x0), but in general something like `Ctrl`+`,` is undefined.  Windowing systems, on the other hand, treat `Ctrl` as a key event modifier, so it can be applied to anything that sends a key event.

Comment: **Thanks**, this is exactly I wanted to know.

Answer (score 0):

... just to add: `C-_` and `C-x u` still work for `C-/` (at least something).